# 'You shall ..... in promises?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, future-tense

When *shall* is used with second person subject, it implies **a promise**.

1. You shall have all you wish for.
2. you shall be the first one to know.
3. *you shall pay a fine.

A)what do the above examples mean when they're used as a promise? (or how *shall* is used to give a promise?)

B)Is it possible to use **third person subjects** in promises?
                  *For example*, ***He** shall get his morney back.

Answer (score 1):

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shall?s=t

Second definition is "will have to, is determined to, or definitely will" -- it's essentially an intensifier of "will." Not only will something happen, but it will *definitely* happen. And the third definition there is that (something) is *legally obliged* to happen. (Or not happen.)

Read the usage note on that page -- it's a little confusing, but gives examples. And below that, there's the *British* definition, which has some small variations from the American ones.

Answer (score -1):

They simply mean what they are. When 'shall' is used as a promise in your first sentence, it can 'promise' someone that they will 'have all they wish for'.

If you are still not sure, then say what you are unsure about and I'll try to explain it.